# Show the eigenvectors are orthogonal with Python

Tags: python

```
M = ( 1 -4  2 )    
     -4  1 -2
      2 -2 -2
```

Question is show the eigenvectors are orthogonal with Python?

This is what I tried: Firstly, I find eigenvectors.

```
A=np.array([[2,0,-1],[0,5,-6],[0,-1,1]])

w,v=np.linalg.eig(A) 
print(w,v)
```

And I don't know what to do next, I guess that I have to use `np.dot()`..

Comment: The question should be to show that the eigenvectors are orthonormal, not the eigenvalues.  You need to find the eigenvectors and then do the dot products.  Eigenvalues are scalars.

Comment: yes, you're right, it's about eigenvectors. thanks.

Comment: Have you understood what it is that [`np.linalg.eig`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) returns?

Comment: it gives eigenvectors and eigenvalues, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have your eigenvectors, take them by pairs `a, b` and check that if they are different, `np.dot(a, b) == 0`